# How can i use a variable created in a objective c Void function?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im trying to get the lat and long values generated in a void function and use them within another function. Any help grateful.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
 float latDeg = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
 NSLog(@"Lat: %g", latDeg);

 float longDeg = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
 NSLog(@"Lat: %g", longDeg);
}
```

I want to use the latDeg and longDeg variables.

Comment: But you're using them in the code already.

Answer (score 3):

Declare `latDeg` and `longDeg` as instance variables in your class. Declaring properties for the instance variables and using them for every access of the variable is optional, but recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse them in the same class, you can just declare them after implementation  of you class. For example `@implementation LocationClass
float latDeg;
float longDeg

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
  didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
         fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
  {
  latDeg = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
  NSLog(@"Lat: %g", latDeg);

  longDeg = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
  NSLog(@"Lat: %g", longDeg);
  }
  `
  that's enough.
  Or you can declare them in you AppDelegater and then use them like:

  YourAppDelegate          *delegate;
  delegate = (YourAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  float currVar = [delegate->longDeg];

Answer (score 0):

a) Make them global variables

b) Make that LocationManager a property of the class you're using it in. You now can add two double-properties to that came class where you might save your latitude or longitude in.

c) Extend your function with another function that takes the lat and lon and writes them to a variable at wherever you need it.

I would highly recommend version b, since it's not only the most simple and cleanest, but it's the only one that does not most likely hurt the OCP at some point.